# Google Sheets Query Giving Error "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Al"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to reorder my columns in sheets and am getting an error stated in the title.

I've made sure that column `AI` does exist in both data source and the formula

```
=QUERY(NumberFix!A1:BL999,"SELECT B, C, D, E, F, BF, G, H, I, K, M, J, L, N, O, Q, S, P, R,
 T, U, V, W, X, BG, Y, AA, AC, Z, AB, AD, AE, AG, AI, AF, AH, AJ, AK, Al, AM, AN, BH, AU,
 AV, AW, AX, AY, AZ, BI, AO, AQ, AR, AS, AT, BA, BB, BC",1)
```

This should resort the data in the order

```
B, C, D, E, F, BF, G, H, I, K, M, J, L, N, O, Q, S, P, R, T, U, V, W, X, BG, Y, AA, AC, Z,
AB, AD, AE, AG, AI, AF, AH, AJ, AK, Al, AM, AN, BH, AU, AV, AW, AX, AY, AZ, BI, AO, AQ, AR,
AS, AT, BA, BB, BC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ### it's not about **`AI`** column
- ### it's because there s no **`Al`** column only **`AL`** column. use:

---

```
=QUERY(NumberFix!A1:BL999, "select B, C, D, E, F, BF, G, H, I, K, M, J, L, N, O, Q, S, P, R,
 T, U, V, W, X, BG, Y, AA, AC, Z, AB, AD, AE, AG, AI, AF, AH, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, BH, AU,
 AV, AW, AX, AY, AZ, BI, AO, AQ, AR, AS, AT, BA, BB, BC", 1)
```